# Using barcode scanner plugin on Phonegap to populate a field/label on HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap-plugins

hopefully somebody can help me with the following. . . if you look at my below code you can see part of my html submission form, I am using a barcode scanner plugin on phonegap build to try and populate one of the fields. The scanner works perfectly but i cannot seem to make it appear in a field similar to my other submission lines... I want it to appear in a field so I can choose to enter serial number manually or use scanner. . . i also want to pull this data to a database. My Javascript is fine as the scanner does work, just doesnt appear in the way i want it to. Id = "info" gives the result of the scanner.

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="addressline1">Address Line 1:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter address of installation" required="required" name="addressline1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="addressline2">Address Line 2:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Please enter address of installation" name="addressline2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="addressline3">Address Line 3:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Please enter address of installation" name="addressline3">
  </div>

 <br>

  <div class="form-group">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="scan">Scan Serial Number</a>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<br>
<h4><strong>Serial Number:</strong></h4><p id="info" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Please use barcode scanner above" required="required" name="info"></p>
</div>
```

```js
var app = {
   
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.getElementById('scan').addEventListener('click', this.scan, false);
        document.getElementById('encode').addEventListener('click', this.encode, false);
    },

  
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },

    scan: function() {
        console.log('scanning');

        var scanner = cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner;

        scanner.scan( function (result) {



           console.log("Scanner result: \n" +
                "text: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "cancelled: " + result.cancelled + "\n");
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = result.text;
            console.log(result);
        
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("Scanning failed: ", error);
        } );
    },

    encode: function() {
        var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");

        scanner.encode(scanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, "http://www.nhl.com", function(success) {
            alert("encode success: " + success);
          }, function(fail) {
            alert("encoding failed: " + fail);
          }
        );

    }

};
```

Comment: I think without JavaScript code you use, you won't get any answer

Comment: please paste your JS snippets, so people can find the issue & provide you some suggestions.

Comment: I have now added the JS file above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out a while ago and forgot to post the answer, it was a very simply fix. Instead of using  use the following . . .  This allows exactly what I needed. Hope this helps somebody else someday.